# Dynamically create pyspark dataframes according to a condition

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe `store_df` :-

| store | ID | Div |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 637 | 4000000970 | Pac |
| 637 | 4000000435 | Pac |
| 637 | 4000055542 | Pac |
| 637 | 4000042206 | Pac |
| 638 | 2200015935 | Pac |
| 638 | 2200000483 | Pac |
| 638 | 4000014114 | Pac |
| 640 | 4000000162 | Pac |
| 640 | 2200000067 | Pac |
| 642 | 2200000067 | Mac |
| 642 | 4000044148 | Mac |
| 642 | 4000014114 | Mac |

I want to remove `ID`(present in store_df) from the dataframe `final_list` dynamically for each `store` in store_df based on `Div`.

`final_list` pyspark df :-

| Div | ID | Rank | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pac | 4000000970 | 1 | A |
| Pac | 4000000432 | 2 | A |
| Pac | 4000000405 | 3 | A |
| Pac | 4000042431 | 4 | A |
| Pac | 2200028596 | 5 | B |
| Pac | 4000000032 | 6 | A |
| Pac | 2200028594 | 7 | B |
| Pac | 4000014114 | 8 | B |
| Pac | 2230001789 | 9 | D |
| Pac | 2200001789 | 10 | C |
| Pac | 2200001787 | 11 | D |
| Pac | 2200001786 | 12 | C |
| Mac | 2200001789 | 1 | C |
| Mac | 2200001787 | 2 | D |
| Mac | 2200001786 | 3 | C |

For eg:for store 637 the `upd_final_list` should look like this(`ID` 4000000970 eliminated):-

| Div | ID | Rank | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pac | 4000000432 | 2 | A |
| Pac | 4000000405 | 3 | A |
| Pac | 4000042431 | 4 | A |
| Pac | 2200028596 | 5 | B |
| Pac | 4000000032 | 6 | A |
| Pac | 2200028594 | 7 | B |
| Pac | 4000014114 | 8 | B |
| Pac | 2230001789 | 9 | D |
| Pac | 2200001789 | 10 | C |
| Pac | 2200001787 | 11 | D |
| Pac | 2200001786 | 12 | C |

Likewise this list is to be customised for other stores based on their `ID`.
How do I do this?

Comment: why is 4000000970 eliminated?

Comment: because its present in `store_df` for store 637 like I mentioned earlier. We want to create final_list dynamically for each store in `store_df`

Comment: ok, so what is the condition you want to eliminate them if they are in store or if the div is "Mac"? can you state the condition in a sentence please?

Comment: we need to see what `Div` the store belongs to for example store 637 belongs to `Div` `Pac`, so we filter `final_list` for `Div` Pac and elimate `ID` present in `store_df` for THAT `store`, 637 in this case and therefore we get a customized `final_list` for each store in `store_df`

Comment: have a look now

Comment: want some way for it to by dynamic for all stores in `store_df`

Comment: well, just change it to a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. Broadcast variables are read-only shared variables that are cached and available on all nodes in a cluster in-order to access or use by the tasks

````
stores=store_df.select("store").distinct().collect()
store_list = [ ele["store"] for ele in stores]
exploded_df = final_list.join(broadcast(store_list_added),['Div'],'left').withColumn('store',explode('store_list')).drop('store_list')
Updated_final_list = exploded_df.join(store_df,['store','ID'],'left_anti')
Updated_final_list=Updated_final_list.withColumn('Rank',col('Rank').cast('int')).withColumn("New_Rank",expr("row_number() over (partition by store order by Rank asc)")).drop("Rank")```
````

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but it should be something like this if I understood it right now

```
store_ids = [637, 123, 865]
for store_id in store_ids: 
   div_type = stores.select("Div").where(f.col("ID") == store_id ).collect()[0][0]
   final_list.join(stores, stores.ID == final_list.ID)
       .select("*")
       .where((f.col("Div") == div_type) &\
              (f.col("store_id") != store_id))
```

Comment: not really we need to elimiate `ID` conditinally for each store . pls re read the questions and expected output

Comment: well, in that case you just have to join them by ID, then execute the query

Comment: it needs to be dynamic list for each store. maybe youi can help by answering the question

Comment: can you add an example? not sure what you mean by dynamic list

Comment: ive added eg for store 637

Comment: what is `db` here?

Comment: your final_list table

Comment: This wont work . look at the pyspark dataframes in question. `final_list` does not have store_id

Comment: They both have ID don't they?

Answer (score 0):

```
store_div = store_df.select('Store','Div').distinct().collect()

fc =0
for i in store_div: 

  store_filter = store_df.filter((col('Store')==i[0]) & (col('Div')==i[1]))
  if fc == 0 :
      Updated_final_list = final_list.join(store_filter, ["ID","DiV"], "left_anti")
  else:
      Updated_final_list = Updated_final_list.join(store_filter, ["ID","DiV"], "left_anti")

  fc +=1
```

Comment: how is this solutuon dynamic for every store is `store_df`?